# Select records from multiple tables in one query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I  have 4 tables not related to each other. I would like to get few records from these tables using one query instead of 4 of them.

At the moment this is being done with 4 queries. Code:

```
<?php

$result1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT val1, val2 FROM `table1` WHERE id='1'") or die(mysqli_error());
    $row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $val1 = $row1['val1'];
    $val2 = $row1['val2'];
    
$result2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT val3, val4 FROM `table2` WHERE id='2'") or die(mysqli_error());
    $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $val3 = $row2['val3'];
    $val4 = $row2['val4'];  

$result3 = $mysqli->query("SELECT val5, val6 FROM `table3` WHERE id='3'") or die(mysqli_error());
    $row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $val5 = $row3['val5'];
    $val6 = $row3['val6'];  
    
$result4 = $mysqli->query("SELECT val7, val8 FROM `table4` WHERE id='4'") or die(mysqli_error());
    $row4 = mysqli_fetch_array($result4, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $val7 = $row4['val7'];
    $val8 = $row4['val8'];
    
?>
```

and my unsuccessful approach to make it in one query. Code:

```
<?php
$resultglobal = $mysqli->query("
SELECT
tab1.val1 AS val1,
tab1.val2 AS val2,
tab2.val3 AS Val3,
tab2.val4 AS val4,
tab3.val5 AS val5,
tab3.val6 AS val6,
tab4.val7 AS val7,
tab4.val8 AS val8

FROM 

table1 as tab1, 
table2 as tab2,
table3 as tab3,    
table4 as tab4

WHERE 

tab1.id='1', 
tab2.id='2', 
tab3.id='3', 
tab4.id='4' 
") or die(mysqli_error());

$rowg = mysqli_fetch_array($resultglobal, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$val1 = $rowg['val1'];
$val2 = $rowg['val2']; 
$val3 = $rowg['val3'];
$val4 = $rowg['val4'];
$val5 = $rowg['val5'];
$val6 = $rowg['val6']; 
$val7 = $rowg['val7'];
$val8 = $rowg['val8'];   
?>
```

What's wrong? What will be a solution here?

Comment: If your four tables truly have **no** relation to each other, then you cannot join them in any way; you will indeed have to make four separate queries. Your first approach is the correct one.

Comment: The data doesn't seem to be related in any meaningful way except that you want it all at once.  Do you have one row per table? Why do you have 4 tables? Can you explain why you want it to be a single query, or if the data is related in any way?

Comment: As you know, correct way to "select records from four different tables" is with a [join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).  But even if they're "unrelated", you might be able to use a [union](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)

Comment: You can `SELECT val1, val2 from table1 UNION SELECT val3, val4 FROM table2...`, then iterate over the result and place into the appropriate values.  You will only get two columns per row though, so you'd have to use indirection and a counter to fill out vals 1-8.

Comment: these tables are being used as a options ( multiple rows per table)

Comment: Options as in "options for a select box"?  Do you want all of the rows in each table?

Comment: This sounds like an [**XY problem**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378), which you may be approaching the [**wrong way**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676). Please clearly indicate exactly what you are trying to do, and why you are trying to do it. What should the end result be? Why do you think this is the correct way of going about it? Please provide some **context** surrounding your question to help clarify your intent. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Comment: I belive if i use one query instead of 4, calculation will be performed faster, am I right?

Comment: It's true there's overhead to each database query, and 4 queries will have 4x the overhead; however, the amount of overhead doesn't matter if the solution doesn't solve the problem.  Be careful of trying to optimize prematurely. If the database is your bottleneck, if we knew more about the problem we could help design a better solution.

Comment: J.D. Pace could you be so kind to expand your solution with UNION. Having difficulty of getting data output (val1, val2 is ok)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to replace `,` WITH `AND` in your `WHERE` clause.
Like this:

```
WHERE
tab1.id='1' AND 
tab2.id='2' AND
...
```

It will work ok as long as ID is unique (e.g. primary key). It is an implicit CROSS JOIN.

Comment: Nice fix. Works as expected. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could do a multi-query this way:

```
$statement = "SELECT val1, val2 FROM `table1` WHERE id='1';";
$statement .= "SELECT val3, val4 FROM `table2` WHERE id='2';";
$statement .= "SELECT val5, val6 FROM `table3` WHERE id='3';";
$statement .= "SELECT val7, val8 FROM `table4` WHERE id='4'";

$values = $mysqli -> multi_query($statement) or die ('Error: '.$mysqli -> error);

while ($row = $values -> fetch_assoc()) {

    $val1 = $row['val1'];
    $val2 = $row['val2'];
    $val3 = $row['val3'];
    $val4 = $row['val4'];
    $val5 = $row['val5'];
    $val6 = $row['val6'];
    $val7 = $row['val7'];
    $val8 = $row['val8'];

}
```

Comment: this solution doesn't work, but gave an idea to another approach with multi-query.